# Parse Json auto add \ into string

Tags: ios, json, swift3, xcode8

My app write by Swift 3.1. And after I get a json from server and parse it into `String`, I got a strange append character. The string respond from server is: `"name" : "nhatlee's store"` but after I parse Json by code `name = dict["name"] as? String` I got the result is `name = Lee Tester\'s Store`. Please help me to correct the way to parse json with this case. Here is the code get data from server:

```
self.requestWith(.post, url: url, parameters: params) { (data, error) in
        if let data = data?["mentions"] as? Array<AnyObject>{
            var mentionObjs = [MentionModel]()
            for obj in data{
                print(obj)
                let mention = MentionModel(from: obj as! [String : AnyObject])
                mentionObjs.append(mention)
            }
            Completion(Result.Success(mentionObjs))
        } else {
        Completion(Result.Failure(error))
        }
    }
```

And json respond is:

```
    {
    email = "nhatlee3@gmail.com";
    id = 516;
    image = "<null>";
    name = nhatlee3;
    "object_class" = User;
}
{
    id = 106;
    image = "<null>";
    name = "Lee Tester's Store";
    "object_class" = Store;
    "user_id" = 352;
}
```

And here is my model object(*I parse json into the model->not sure that the good way for code structure, please let me some advices if you have a better ways*):

```
    struct MentionModel {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var imageUrl: String?
    var objectClass: String?
    init(from dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
        id          = dict["id"] as? Int
        name        = dict["name"] as? String
        imageUrl    = dict["image"] as? String
        objectClass = dict["object_class"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code how you are getting JSON response, And why you are parsing it to string instead of dictionary or array

Comment: @NiravD please view the update question.

Comment: Also show the `requestWith` because in this method you are serializing the dictionary

Comment: I use `Alamorefire` to call request to the server

Comment: I will suggest you to use the SwiftyJson library for the json parsing.

Comment: can you add your json response ?

Comment: if you got name = Lee Tester\'s Store this string ...then what wrong here ?

Comment: The problem is I got the unexpected character "\"